# Prove the free monoid $M(A)+M(B)\cong M(A + B)$

Tags: category-theory

I am self-studying category theory via the textbook of Awodey. And this is an exercise in the book, namely 3.5.2

> Show in detail that the free monoid functor M preserves coproducts: for any sets $A,B, M(A)+M(B)\cong M(A + B)$ (canonically). Do this as indicated in the text by using the UMPs of the coproducts $A+B$ and $M(A)+M(B)$ and of free monoids.

(I did look up the solution, but I can do not think it is easy to follow. And from the line " Suppose $h : MA+MB→ Z$ has the property that $Uh◦e = f$", I cannot understand it since it seems that the author did not prove that such a map does exist. So I prefer to proceed using the map constructed by myself.)

The following is my attempt:

To prove that $M(A)+M(B)\cong M(A + B)$, I want to prove that $M(A)+M(B)$ satisfies the UMP of $M(A+B)$. Namely, I need to prove:

> There is a function $e:A+B\to |M(A)+M(B)|$, and given any function $f:A+B\to Z$, there is a unique monoid homomorphism $\overline{f}:M(A)+M(B)\to Z$ such that $|\overline{f}|\circ e=f$.

I construct an $e$ and an $|\overline{f}|=h$ as follows:

[image]

For the e:

Say $i_{M(A)},i_{M(B)}$ arre injections into the coproduct $M(A)+M(B)$, and $\eta_A,\eta_B$ are injections into the free monoid $M(A)$ and $M(B)$ respectively. Then by UMP of coproduct $M(A)+M(B)$, we have a unique map $e:A+B\to M(A)+M(B)$ such that the lower part of the diagram above commute.

For the $h=|\overline{f}|$:

Let an monoid $Z$ and an arrow $f:A+B\to |Z|$ be given, Then we have $A\overset{f\circ i_A}\rightarrow Z$. By the UMP of free monoid, we have the map $\overline{f\circ i_A}$ such that the digram below commutes:

[image]

So by the UMP of $M(A)+M(B)$, we have a unique h such that the upper part of the big diagram above commutes. As both the upper and lower part of the diagram commutes, the whold diagram commutes. By the UMP of the coproduct $A+B$, the middle map that commutes with the outside of the diagram is unique, so we have $f=h\circ e$.

My difficulty is to prove that such an h is unique. We are not given that $e$ is a epi so we cannot deduce $h=h'$ from $h\circ e=h'\circ e=f$.

For those who want to say that $h$ is unique by construction, I want to say that how do we know that the $h$ we construct is the only map with the desired property?

Any help with this point, please?

Thanks for your patience of reading it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $h,h'\colon MA+MB\to Z.$ These are distinct if and only if $h\circ i_{MA},h'\circ i_{MA}\colon MA\to Z$ are distinct, or else the ones for $MB$ (because maps out of the coproduct $MA+MB$ are in one-to-one correspondence with cocones on $MA,MB$.) But maps $MA\to Z$ are in one-to-one correspondence with maps $A\to |Z|$ (UMP of free monoids). But distinct maps $A\to |Z|$ means distinct maps $A+B\to |Z|$ (coproducts/cocones again). If those are not distinct (because you stipulate they both equal $f$), then neither are $h,h'.$