# proving free monoid preserves coproduct

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to prove the title. I've looked up solutions on the internet and found following two

[Prove the free monoid $M(A)+M(B)\cong M(A + B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575244/prove-the-free-monoid-mamb-cong-ma-b)

https://abstractnonsenseblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/categorical-proof-that-the-free-monoid-functor-preserves-coproducts/

But both use slightly different approach than mine and I am not sure how to converge the arguments, so I am asking.

[image]

where $N$ is any monoid. My goal is to prove by the definition of coproduct, therefore I want to show $v$ is unique.

From the diagram, I know

$$f = uh = vji = vkh$$

Therefore $uh = vkh$. I also know $vj$ needs to be unique by UMP of $A+B$ and $N$.

But I am very confused now about why the top two triangles commute. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u$ and $vk$ are both monoid homomorphisms whose composition with $h$ is $f$, $u=vk$ by the uniqueness part of the universal property of $M(A)$.  The right triangle commutes similarly.

In general, when you want to prove two morphisms are equal in a context like this (and it doesn't just formally pop out of other diagrams that you know commute), that usually means you want to use the uniqueness part of a universal property.

Comment: Ouch, that was easy. Thanks. Sometimes it's really difficult to wrap my head around.